# reading from a xml and bind to treeview after eliminating the rootnode and firstchild node

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have a xml file of the structure

```
<MainList>
<number>5<number/>
<first id="1" name="test" />
<second/>
<third/>
<MainList/>
```

Now i want to display this in a treeview by eliminating the "MainList" and "number"

I want the tree to display in the format

```
first
  id
  name
second
third
```

I am using xmlreader now

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have to use `XmlReader` or is it possible to use `XDocument` instead?

Comment: i had listed the xml with xmlreader..But i am only able to list the full xml ie,without eliminating the "MainList" and "number".

Comment: By the way, there's a typo in your XML: `<number>5<number/>` should be `<number>5</number>` and `<MainList/>` should be `</MainList>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by @AS-CII here ( [Binding hierarchical xml to treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5437713/314334) ), you could modify the code posted there to satisfy your needs.

1. Skip root element and the first child element
2. Add first-level-`TreeNode`s directly to the `Nodes`-collection of the `TreeView` (since there is no root element)
3. Create `TreeNode` for `Attribute` as well as for `Element`

For example:

```
private void Form1_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    string xml = "<MainList><number>5</number><first id=\"1\" name=\"test\" /><second/><third/></MainList>";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse ( xml );
    var elements = doc.Root // "MainList"
        .Elements () // Elements inside "MainList"
        .Skip ( 1 ); // Skip first item ("number")
    // Add a TreeNode for each element on first level (inside MainList)
    foreach ( var item in elements )
    {
        // Create first-level-node
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode ( item.Name.LocalName );
        // Create subtree, if necessary
        TreeNode[] nodes = this.GetNodes ( node, item ).ToArray ();
        // Add node with subtree to TreeView
        treeView1.Nodes.AddRange ( nodes );
    }
}
```

The code above uses following method to create TreeNodes from the elements and attributes of the XML document:

```
private IEnumerable<TreeNode> GetNodes ( TreeNode node, XElement element )
{
    List<TreeNode> result = new List<TreeNode> ();
    // First, create TreeNodes for attributes of current element and add them to the result
    if ( element.HasAttributes )
        result.AddRange ( node.AddRange (
            from item in element.Attributes ()
            select new TreeNode ( "[A] " + item.Name.LocalName ) ) );
    // Next, create subtree and add it to the result
    if ( element.HasElements )
        result.AddRange ( node.AddRange ( 
            from item in element.Elements ()
            let tree = new TreeNode ( item.Name.LocalName )
            from newNode in GetNodes ( tree, item )
            select newNode ) );
    // If there aren't any attributes or subelements, return the node that was originally passed in
    if ( result.Count == 0 )
        result.Add ( node );
    // Return the result 
    return result;
}
```

Furthermore, you need this extension method:

```
public static class TreeNodeEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AddRange ( this TreeNode collection, IEnumerable<TreeNode> nodes )
    {
        collection.Nodes.AddRange ( nodes.ToArray () );
        return new[] { collection };
    }
}
```