# Display XML data in TreeView control using LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, linq-to-xml

How to display XML data in TreeView control using Linq To XML 
and Also In contrast save TreeView data in XML by using Linq

example xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<factors>
  <factor number="1" price="1000">
    <code>12</code>
    <group>A</group>
  </factor>
</factors>
```

I'm using Windows Forms and C#

Comment: Where did you reach so far ?

Comment: Take a loot at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437713/binding-hierarchical-xml-to-treeview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse your XML and depending on what XML elements you want as nodes add them:

```
var xmlSource = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                    <factors>
                        <factor number=""1"" price=""1000"">
                            <code>12</code>
                            <group>A</group>
                        </factor>
                        <factor number=""2"" price=""10"">
                            <code>1</code>
                            <group>B</group>
                        </factor>
                    </factors>";

var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlSource);
var factors = xml.Root.Descendants("factor").ToList();
// create tree and add root node
// TreeView tr = new TreeView();
// var root = tr.Nodes.Add("Factors");
foreach (var factor in factors)
{
    var nodeNumber = factor.Attribute("number").Value;
    var subNodeCode = factor.Element("code").Value;
    // add attribute as node name
    // var node = root.Nodes.Add(nodeNumber);
    // add elements as sub nodes
    // node.Nodes.Add(subNodeCode)
}
```

The code for saving from the tree to XML is exactly the same, just in the oposite direction - iterate through all nodes and extract and build the xml elements and/or attributes. You should know best which element or attribute you want to show as tree node and vice versa.

Read the documentation for the [TreeView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx) and LINQ2XML starting for example from the [XDocument helper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

---

Assuming that your TreeView is named tree, then with the following code you can create quickly a XML document from the nodes:

```
var xml = new XDocument();
var rootElement = new XElement("factors");
foreach (TreeNode node in tree.Nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes)
    {
        var attribute = new XAttribute("number", subNode.Text);
        var element = new XElement("factor", attribute);
        foreach (TreeNode subSubNode in subNode.Nodes)
        {
            var subElement = new XElement("code", subSubNode.Text);
            element.Add(subElement);
        }
        rootElement.Add(element);
    }
}
xml.Add(rootElement);
xml.ToString(); // gives you the XML code
// OR save the XML directly to file
//xml.Save(@"c:\temp\output.xml");
```

Far better and efficient would be to write a recursive function that gives you filled XElement object back. You should also use the [Tag TreeNode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) to store the information for every TreeNode.

Comment: thx @pasty but now, how can save TreeView data in XML by using Linq?

Comment: I have added sample code for creating and saving the XML from the tree nodes in my answer.