# I want to create treeview (parent and child and grandchild and so on), depending on xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml file and has 200 node, as that:

```
<grand name="AAA"       id="1"      father="0"></grand>
<grand name="BBB"       id="2"      father="1"></grand> 
<grand name="CCC"       id="3"      father="1"></grand>  
<grand name="DDD"       id="4"      father="2"></grand>  
<grand name="EEE"       id="5"      father="2"></grand>  
<grand name="FFF"       id="6"      father="5"></grand>  
<grand name="GGG"       id="7"      father="5"></grand>  
<grand name="HHH"       id="8"      father="5"></grand>  
<grand name="III"       id="9"      father="6"></grand>  
<grand name="JJJ"       id="10"     father="7"></grand>
```

I want to create treeview so, the first nodetree for the node that its father atrribute is "0", then each nodetree has child nodetree for each xmlnode, so treeview has one grandfather, then he has tow childs, and the tow childs has child also and the last childs also have child and so on.
now i write c# code for that:

```
public struct person
        {
            public string id;
            public string name;
            public string father;
            public string child;
        }
        XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Parse(Fulltree.Properties.Resources.index);
        person[] arr = new person[200];
        TreeNode[] tn = new TreeNode[200];
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            setlist();
            createtree(); 

        }

        public void setlist()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 200) { 
            var str = (from n in xmldoc.Descendants("grand")
                                        where n.Attribute("id").Value == (i+1).ToString()
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Name = n.Attribute("name").Value,
                                            Sex = n.Attribute("sex").Value,
                                            Status = n.Attribute("status").Value,
                                            Child = n.Attribute("child").Value,
                                            Id = n.Attribute("id").Value,
                                            Father = n.Attribute("father").Value
                                        }).First();
            {
                arr[i].id = str.Id.ToString();
                arr[i].child = str.Child.ToString();
                arr[i].name = str.Name.ToString();
                arr[i].father = str.Father.ToString();
                tn[i] = new TreeNode(str.Id);
                tn[i].Text = str.Name.ToString();
            }
            i+=1;
                           }// end while

            } //end setlist

        public void createtree()
        {
            AddAllChildren(arr[0], 0);
        }

  public  void AddAllChildren( person[] arr , int parentIndex ) {
    for (int childIndex = parentIndex+1; childIndex < arr.Length; ++childIndex)
            {
                if( arr[childIndex].father == arr[parentIndex].id ) {
                    tn[parentIndex].Nodes.Add(tn[childIndex]);
                  AddAllChildren( arr[childIndex], childIndex );
                                                                     }
              }
                                                              }
```

now when i run this code i get message that i must do stub for AddallChild method, when i do that, i get error :( The method or operation is not implemented.) at line (1), down

```
private void AddAllChildren(person person, int p)
 {
        throw new NotImplementedException();    line(1)
 }
```

thanks for all

Comment: well, it's the code that says it should throw a not implemented exception, remove the error and implement the code for it ;)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437713/binding-hierarchical-xml-to-treeview for a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have by accident generated another method AddAllChildren.
Try removing it.

TreeNode constructor new TreeNode(str.Id); creates node with Text = str.Id
later you overwrite it with:

```
tn[i].Text = str.Name.ToString();
```

You are going through xml in every step of loop, instead of doing it once.

```
 public void setlist()
        {
            var allPeople = xmldoc.Descendants("grand").Select(n => new person
                                          {
                                              name = n.Attribute("name").Value,
                                              /*Sex = n.Attribute("sex").Value,   //never used
                                              Status = n.Attribute("status").Value, //never used*/
                                              child = n.Attribute("child").Value,
                                              id = n.Attribute("id").Value,
                                              father = n.Attribute("father").Value
                                          }).ToList();

            var rootTreeNode = GetTree(allPeople, "0").First();
            //do something with rootTreeNode....
        }
        private TreeNode[] GetTree(List<person> allPeople, string parent)
        {
            return allPeople.Where(p => p.father == parent).Select(p =>
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(p.name);
                node.Tag = p;
                node.Nodes.AddRange(GetTree(allPeople, p.id));
                return node;
            }).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: thank you Mr. lukbl. that exact what I want. thank you