# Create Treeview depending on DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, database

I get data from tow database, db1,db2, then Now I want to create treeView for the data in the resulting datagridview; in datagrid view there are: id, name, director,the first record is the prim director, that mean he has not up director(he is owner), each record has no other record or has more records(child), and each child has grandchild and so on, this scenario Just Like in the this page:
[I want to create treeview (parent and child and grandchild and so on), depending on xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31609996/i-want-to-create-treeview-parent-and-child-and-grandchild-and-so-on-depending)
when i used this snippet after some :

```
void setTree()
        {
            {
            foreach(DataGridViewRow dt in DataGridView1.Rows)
            { 
          var per = this.DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(n => new person
                {
                    name = dt.Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                    Sex = dt.Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                    Status = dt.Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                    child = dt.Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                    id = dt.Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                    father = dt.Cells[5].Value.ToString()
                }).ToList();
               var rootTreeNode = GetTree(per, "").First();.........(1)
               treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootTreeNode);
            }
          }
        }
               private TreeNode[] GetTree(List<person> per, string parent)
        {
            return per.Where(p => p.father == parent).Select(p =>
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(p.name);
                node.Tag = p.id;
                node.Nodes.AddRange(GetTree(per, p.id));
                return node;
            }).ToArray();
        }
```

Now, when I use this code, I get error at mark(1),it say:Additional information: Sequence contains no elements.

thank you

Comment: You have syntax errors, fix those first.

Comment: where is the syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after several readings in internet and attempts to solve this small problem, I successed finally.
this is the solution:

```
{
.............
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(this.DataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());//text
tn.Tag = this.DataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();// id
tn.Name = this.DataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();//directorid
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
                settree(tn);
            }
            public void settree(TreeNode ns)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in DataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString() == ns.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    TreeNode tsn = new TreeNode(dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                    tsn.Tag = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                    tsn.Name = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                    ns.Nodes.Add(tsn);
                    settree(tsn);
                }
            }
        }
```

i will be happy if you benefit from this code.