# .Net C# best way to save treeView to file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, treeview

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and C#. I'm creating a TreeView dynamically and have Add and Delete buttons to create the tree.

I'm wondering what would be a good way to save the treeView nodes to a file so that I can build it dynamically again when the application starts up next time?

Should I use an .ini file? .xml? And I'd like to see an example of how that might be done. A small example is fine.

Thanks...

Comment: I would go with XML... or probably JSON

Comment: XML, try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437713/binding-hierarchical-xml-to-treeview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both formats to store your data. Regardless of the format, you need to define a class with an Id which represents each node and a parentId which can be null for root elements. Than you should set a list of elements and then serialize those. The serialized object can be saved as Xml, or parsed into any other format like Json or even custom format like ini file.

### Edit 1

This is a sample implementation. The data structure is not a valid tree, but it gives you a perspective. Maybe you can read more about trees [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            // Define your initial tree nodes.
            var tree = new List<TreeNode>
            {
                new TreeNode
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    ParentId = null,
                    Text = "Root Element 1"
                },
                new TreeNode
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    ParentId = null,
                    Text = "Root Element 2"
                },
                new TreeNode
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    ParentId = 1,
                    Text = "Child Element 1"
                },
                new TreeNode
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    ParentId = 3,
                    Text = "Grandchild Element 1"
                }
            };

            // Initialize serializer instance.
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(tree.GetType());

            // Serialize your list. (Save into Xml File)
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("SerializerTest.xml"))
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(fileStream, tree);
            }

            // Deserialize your stored Xml file into a new tree object.
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("SerializerTest.xml"))
            {
                var loadedTree = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as List<TreeNode>;
                if (loadedTree != null)
                {
                    foreach (var node in loadedTree.Where(x => x.ParentId == null).ToList())
                    {
                        PrintNode(loadedTree, node);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void PrintNode(List<TreeNode> tree, TreeNode node)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} - Text: {1}", node.Id, node.Text);
            var children = tree.Where(x => x.ParentId == node.Id).ToList();
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                PrintNode(tree, child);
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class TreeNode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those answers...how would I create the .xml file as a save tasks? Those links show me how to load in an .xml file and build the treeView, but how do I save the treeView to get the .xml file?